# How can Spring life cycle methods be prevented when using Java Config?

Tags: java, spring, spring-java-config

How can I prevent the @PostConstruct method on the ProblematicSerivce from being invoked by Spring after I return the object?

```
@Configuration
class MyConfig {
    @Bean
    public ProblematicService problematicService() {
        ProblematicService service = someMethodOutsideMyControl();
        // ProblematicService is constructed for me by other code (outside of Spring)
        // and it happens to have a @PostConstruct method. The @PostConstruct method
        // cannot be invoked here or by Spring once this method returns.
        return service;
    }
}
```

I believe wrapping the result in a FactoryBean would have the desired effect, but I need to repeat this code in several places, so I'm looking for a more elegant solution.

Comment: I don't understand: you have a `@Bean` problematicService() where you construct a `ProblematicService`, but you say that it's "constructed for me by other code". You want to say that you have access to `ProblematicService` from an API and you need to build it, but the API comes with a `@PostConstruct` annotation and you cannot change that?

Comment: Yes, ProblematicService comes to me already constructed from code outside my control.

Comment: Are you every going to call the `@PostConstruct` annotated method? And is `ProblematicService` declared as `final`?

Comment: Its @PostConstruct method has already been called and cannot be called a second time. The class is probably not final. I'm hoping there was a "right" Spring way of dealing with this that I hadn't found.

Comment: What I mean is: you don't want to call the `@PostConstruct` method automatically by Spring. Are you ever going to invoke it elsewhere?

Comment: The method was called before I had a reference to the object. If Spring invokes it, an Exception will be thrown.

Comment: OK, please update your question with that detail.

Comment: Do you have any other `@PostConstruct` annotated beans that _do_ need to run?

Comment: Could `@Bean(initMethod="")` be of any use ? If I correctly understand javadocs, it should override the use of `@PostConstruct` - but I could'nt test it ...

Comment: There are no other @PostConstruct methods. I just want to return the bean as-is without any of the lifecycle methods being executed.

Comment: @SergeBallesta No, `initMethod` and `@PostConstruct` are handled by separate components.

Answer (score 4):

This is a non-trivial change. A `@Configuration` class (or rather the `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext`) registers a `CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` which is in charge of invoking the `@PostConstruct` method of a bean. Changing that would mean changing almost the whole Spring IoC stack.

**Actually**, you could just declare a `CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` with a bean name `org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor` which will override the default one. You can sett the init annotation type to `null` so that it ignores `@PostConstruct`.

```
@Bean(name = "org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor")
public CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor commonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor() {
    CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor bean = new CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor();
    bean.setInitAnnotationType(null);;
    return bean;
}
```

Careful while using this as it might break other things.

I'm going to first recommend to try and find a way around that. For example, return a wrapper object which can give you access to the `ProblematicService`.

```
@Bean
public ServiceProvider provider() {
    ProblematicService service = ...;
    ServiceProvider provider = new ServiceProvider(service);
    return provider;
}
```

Or similarly the `FactoryBean` you suggested.

Another, cooler, but uglier way to do it is to wrap the object in a CGLIB proxy.

```
@Bean
public ProblematicService service() {
    ProblematicService service = ...;
    Enhancer enhancer = new Enhancer();
    enhancer.setSuperclass(service.getClass());
    enhancer.setCallback(new MethodInterceptor() {
        ProblematicService inner = service;
        @Override
        public Object intercept(Object obj, Method method, Object[] args,
                    MethodProxy proxy) throws Throwable {
            if (!method.getName().equals("initMethodName"))
                return method.invoke(inner, args);
            return null;
        }
    });
    return (ProblematicService) enhancer.create();
}
```

Basically the init-method can never be called.

Comment: Nice CGLib solution, really smart! +1! But what happens if ProblematicService has some transactional behavior which forces Spring to create a JDK dynamic proxy for it. Won't that break the CGLib implementation since CGLib proxies can't be created on JDK proxies?

Comment: @geoand Good point. We'd have to test if CGLIB classes can be proxied. I'll brb. In the meantime, I've given a cleaner solution.

Comment: Yes I saw your updated solution, and I must say I like it too! I have to admit I wasn't aware of the fact that declaring a bean of type post processor will force Spring to drop the default registered one. Good stuff!!!

Comment: @geoand So CGLIB can subclass other CGLIB classes, but the implementation has to be smart enough when naming the types. I don't know if Spring's is. If it is, there should be no issue. You'll just have `Transactional Proxy -> Your Proxy -> Target`. If it isn't, you'll find out when initializing the context.

Comment: @OP All the solutions I can think of really depend on the rest of your configuration. Keep that in mind.